# Как использовать ActiveRecord из фрэймворка yii2 для подключения к таблице org из схемы data

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, yii2

описал модель org и пытаюсь сделать запрос использующий её 
`org::find()->where('id='.$_GET['id'])->one();`

Однако получаю ошибку:

Database Exception – yii\db\Exception

SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ОШИБКА: отношение "org" не существует
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM "org" WHERE id=321

Как указать что org находиться в схеме data

Comment: нужно видеть как вы описали модель

Comment: class org extends ActiveRecord {}

Comment: модель сам создавал или через gii?

Comment: Покажите код модели и схему данных БД. Или воспользуйтесь генератором модели gii - всё пропишет, в том числе и связи (если у вас связи в БД установлены и таблица innoDB)

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в модель org метод tableName:

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'data.org';
}
```